# Animating Polyline fails with Lat/Long Array

Tags: javascript, google-maps, animation, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to use google.maps.geometry.spherical.interpolate to animate a set of Lat/Long. I can successfully animate two Lat/Long points, but when I try to loop through them I do not see all points animate. What is wrong with my approach?

Here is how to animate just two points: http://jsfiddle.net/4kgg7536/9/

```js
function initMap() {   
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
 'zoom': 10,
   'center': new google.maps.LatLng(25.969937410307143, -80.0804620727539),
   'mapTypeId': google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
   'scrollwheel': true,
   'draggable':true
  });
  
  var flightPath = {
    one: [
   new google.maps.LatLng(26.248630099430756,-80.05024967041015), 
    new google.maps.LatLng(26.136493049813648, -80.16423282470703),        
    new google.maps.LatLng(26.034120197851937,-80.04475650634765), 
    new google.maps.LatLng(25.957590547577706,-80.1573663696289), 
    new google.maps.LatLng(25.827870363354016,-80.03239688720703), 
   new google.maps.LatLng(25.698007870576784,-80.14500675048828)
    ]};
  
  var flightSymbol = {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_OPEN_ARROW,
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    scale: 3
  };
 
  var pathSymbol = {
    path: 'M 0,-0.5 0,0.5',
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    strokeWeight:3,
    scale: 4
  }  
 
   flightRoute = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPath.one,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeOpacity: 0,
    icons: [
   {
     icon: flightSymbol,
     offset: '100%'
   }, {
     icon: pathSymbol,
     offset: '0',
     repeat: '15px'
   },
    ],
    strokeOpacity: 0,
    strokeColor: '#f00',
    map: map
  });
 
   var departure = flightPath['one'][0];
  var arrival = flightPath['one'][4];
   
  var step = 0;
  var numSteps = 500; //Change this to set animation resolution
  var timePerStep = 5; //Change this to alter animation speed
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
  step += 1;
  if (step > numSteps) {
      clearInterval(interval);
  } else {
     var are_we_there_yet = google.maps.geometry.spherical.interpolate(departure,arrival,step/numSteps);
     flightRoute.setPath([departure, are_we_there_yet]);
    }
   }, timePerStep);
 }
```

```html
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&callback=initMap&libraries=geometry"></script>
<div  id="map" style="width: 525px;height: 500px;"></div>
```

Now here I try to animate the set of lat/longs without success:

```js
function initMap() {   
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
 'zoom': 10,
   'center': new google.maps.LatLng(25.969937410307143, -80.0804620727539),
   'mapTypeId': google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
   'scrollwheel': true,
   'draggable':true
  });
  
  var flightPath = {
    one: [
   new google.maps.LatLng(26.248630099430756,-80.05024967041015), 
    new google.maps.LatLng(26.136493049813648, -80.16423282470703),        
    new google.maps.LatLng(26.034120197851937,-80.04475650634765), 
    new google.maps.LatLng(25.957590547577706,-80.1573663696289), 
    new google.maps.LatLng(25.827870363354016,-80.03239688720703), 
   new google.maps.LatLng(25.698007870576784,-80.14500675048828)
    ]};
  
  var flightSymbol = {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_OPEN_ARROW,
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    scale: 3
  };
 
  var pathSymbol = {
    path: 'M 0,-0.5 0,0.5',
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    strokeWeight:3,
    scale: 4
  }  
 
   flightRoute = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPath.one,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeOpacity: 0,
    icons: [
   {
     icon: flightSymbol,
     offset: '100%'
   }, {
     icon: pathSymbol,
     offset: '0',
     repeat: '15px'
   },
    ],
    strokeOpacity: 0,
    strokeColor: '#f00',
    map: map
  });
 
for(i=0;i<=flightPath['one'].length-2;i++)
  {
   var departure = flightPath['one'][i];
  var arrival = flightPath['one'][i+1];
   
  var step = 0;
  var numSteps = 500; //Change this to set animation resolution
  var timePerStep = 5; //Change this to alter animation speed
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
  step += 1;
  if (step > numSteps) {
      clearInterval(interval);
  } else {
     var are_we_there_yet = google.maps.geometry.spherical.interpolate(departure,arrival,step/numSteps);
     flightRoute.setPath([departure, are_we_there_yet]);
    }
   }, timePerStep);
       }
 }
```

```html
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&callback=initMap&libraries=geometry"></script>
<div  id="map" style="width: 525px;height: 500px;"></div>
```

The snippet above has the following change where I put everything inside of a for-loop, however only the last two points animate. I am not clearing the map, so why is it that only the last two points show?

```
for(i=0;i<=flightPath['one'].length-2;i++)
{
    var departure = flightPath['one'][i];
    var arrival = flightPath['one'][i+1];

    var step = 0;
    var numSteps = 500; //Change this to set animation resolution
    var timePerStep = 5; //Change this to alter animation speed
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
    step += 1;

    if (step > numSteps) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    } else {
             var are_we_there_yet = google.maps.geometry.spherical.interpolate(departure,arrival,step/numSteps);
             flightRoute.setPath([departure, are_we_there_yet]);
         }
    }, timePerStep);
}
```

Comment: Why the down-vote? What more do I need to post to show effort? I am confused.. why down-vote without providing a constructive comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`google.maps.geometry.spherical.interpolate` only works between two points on the polyline.  You need to update your setInterval function to handle multiple sets of points.  Putting it in inside the for loop will only run between the last two points in the polyline (the loop iterates to the last set of points, then the set interval function runs).

If you want the polyline to stay between the earlier points you have to create a new one to fill in the previous history.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/trnh7frz/4/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var flightRoute, flightRouteCompleted;

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    'zoom': 10,
    'center': new google.maps.LatLng(25.969937410307143, -80.0804620727539),
    'mapTypeId': google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
    'scrollwheel': true,
    'draggable': true
  });

  var flightPath = {
    one: [
      new google.maps.LatLng(26.248630099430756, -80.05024967041015),
      new google.maps.LatLng(26.136493049813648, -80.16423282470703),
      new google.maps.LatLng(26.034120197851937, -80.04475650634765),
      new google.maps.LatLng(25.957590547577706, -80.1573663696289),
      new google.maps.LatLng(25.827870363354016, -80.03239688720703),
      new google.maps.LatLng(25.698007870576784, -80.14500675048828)
    ]
  };
  for (var i = 0; i < flightPath["one"].length; i++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: flightPath["one"][i],
      map: map,
      title: "" + i
    })
  }

  var flightSymbol = {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_OPEN_ARROW,
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    scale: 3
  };

  var pathSymbol = {
    path: 'M 0,-0.5 0,0.5',
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    strokeWeight: 3,
    scale: 4
  }

  flightRoute = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPath.one,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeOpacity: 0,
    icons: [{
      icon: flightSymbol,
      offset: '100%'
    }, {
      icon: pathSymbol,
      offset: '0',
      repeat: '15px'
    }, ],
    strokeOpacity: 0,
    strokeColor: '#f00',
    map: map
  });
  flightRouteCompleted = new google.maps.Polyline({
    geodesic: true,
    strokeOpacity: 0,
    icons: [{
      icon: pathSymbol,
      offset: '0',
      repeat: '15px'
    }, ],
    strokeOpacity: 0,
    strokeColor: '#f00',
    map: map
  });
  var departure = flightPath["one"][0];
  var arrival = flightPath['one'][1];
  var i = 0;
  var step = 0;
  var numSteps = 500; //Change this to set animation resolution
  var timePerStep = 5; //Change this to alter animation speed
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    step += 1;
    if (i >= (flightPath["one"].length - 1)) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    } else if (step > numSteps) {
      i++;
      step = 0;
      departure = flightPath["one"][i];
      arrival = flightPath['one'][i + 1];
      if (i == 1) {
        flightRouteCompleted.setPath([flightPath["one"][0]]);
      }
      flightRouteCompleted.getPath().push(flightPath["one"][i]);
    } else {
      var are_we_there_yet = google.maps.geometry.spherical.interpolate(departure, arrival, step / numSteps);
      flightRoute.setPath([departure, are_we_there_yet]);
    }
  }, timePerStep);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
<div id="map" style="width: 525px;height: 500px;"></div>
```

Comment: This is perfect, except it is generating the following error if you look in the console when the animation reaches the last marker:

*js?v=3.exp&callback=initMap&libraries=geometry:46 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined*

Comment: That should be fixed (the termination condition wasn't working)

Comment: Fantastic work, I will learn from this, thank you sir! I have up-voted and accepted your answer.